# File Handles and Logging in Node JS

Tags: node.js, file, handle

I have an application that will log data to a text file anytime the application is used. It may be used once a day or maybe once every second.

Is there anything wrong with me opening a handle to the text file and keeping it open as long as my application is running and never close it? This way I can just append data to the log without reopening the file handle. Are there consequences to this decision I should be aware of?

Comment: I'm curious, are you thinking of creating a write stream and simply not closing it, but just calling `write` again and again ([similar to the code mentioned here](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain))?

Comment: I'm thinking of just calling write again and again, haven't considered creating a write stream

Comment: If you're thinking about `fs.write` you might consider the note in the [API doc](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback): "Note that it is unsafe to use fs.write multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended."

Comment: Consequences aside, I prefer to not make log targets a concern of my application.  Following the 12-factor principles, you just console.log or console.error everything, and then let the OS handle redirecting to a file, db, whatever, in the environment.  Much cleaner / more portable.

Comment: Any particular reason of doing it yourself instead of using an existant (and proven) module? There are lots of them: https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/logs

Answer (score 1):

`fs.open` returns a  file descriptor and if you don't close connection it may result in file descriptors leak. The file descriptor won't be closed, even if there's an error.

on the other hand, `fs.readFile`, `fs.writeFile`,`fs.appendFile` , `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream` don't return a file descriptor. They open the file , operate on it and then close the file.